# Is it expected that SQLAzure is unavailable from time to time?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am connecting to SQLAzure from my Azure service.

Most of the time, things work fine.

However, once in a while (about once a day), I am unable to connect. It lasts about 5 minutes.

I get the following error:

> SQLException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Is this to be expected?

Is it part of cloud programming?

Am I supposed to program defensively against it?

Comment: general rule: always program defensively. manytimes moreso when dealing with cloud services.

Comment: Whilst people seem to think this is to be expected, I disagree. Obviously, occasional connectivity issues do occur but they should only last a few seconds or so - something that the transient fault application block can take care off. Having your database regularly unavailable for several minutes which you (and I) have experienced is far more of an issue that IMO should not be happening in Azure. Recently, I am experiencing far more issues with SQL Azure than I have experienced on AppHarbor or shared hosting - so much so that I am looking at alternative persistence strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected. It is expected in your connections and commands you build some kind of retry logic. How hard this is depends on your data layer.

There is lots of info on google
https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+azure+transient

[Entity Framework - SQL Azure Retry Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703428/entity-framework-sql-azure-retry-policy)

Answer (score 1):

This type of behavior is expected for SQL Azure and as well as for other cloud services. Microsoft provides the [Transient Fault Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) which includes robust transient fault handling logic for various Azure services, including SQL Azure.