# Connection to SQL Azure DB is unstable

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm having a strange error with a recently deployed Azure website.
Everything seems to work most of the time, but on a regular basis (at least daily) there is a period during which I receive following error:
    A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
    The server was not found or was not accessible.

Is this a stability issue with Azure or is it possible that something's wrong in my code (but why does it work then most of the time)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976118/is-it-expected-that-sqlazure-is-unavailable-from-time-to-time

Answer (score 4):

Is the code using the Transient Fault Handling Application Block - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934(v=PandP.50).aspx? This block understands how to handle the transient errors that can, and will, happen with SQL Database.