# Entity Framework error: A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

About 30 min ago I got this error on my production server:

```
A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
```

This error appeared out nowhere (i.e. I haven't changed anything on server nor on database). I'm using  Microsoft Azure Cloud Services and their SQL server V12. And I cannot find why this is happening. Everything behaved normal (usual amount of requests to the server, DTU percentage was around 10% etc.) and out of nowhere this happened.

Also there are only 4 SQL connections that are active in the moment. And Evry connection to SQL is closed because Database Context is disposed via using pattern.

What is interesting, when I run project locally everything works fine. Of course I tired to reboot my Cloud server instances, but that didn't help.

Could anyone please help me ?

**EDIT**

Due to severity of the problem (as this happened in production with while bunch of users were online), I've created Copy of DB trough Azure portal and pointed my Web and API project to that DB and now everything works fine. But this is not exactly solution to the problem.

**EDIT 2**
This started to happen again on new database :(

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to SQL Connection remains open. Please make sure every connection is close after used.
Please try to use the code below:
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
Also monitor your SQL server for the connections that are open.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response, I've Edited my question so it contains more details (such as num of sql connections -  which is only 4). So this doesn't help me

Comment: Sorry, your edited statement are contradiction with active connection and closed both. so 4 active connection you are talking please try to close that.

Comment: That didn't help :(

Comment: 1. Recycling app pools.
2. Restarting the web application.
3. Restarting IIS.
4. Restarting SQL server.

Comment: Please try to follow above steps

Comment: Hey Azure SQL server cannot be restarted. And Restarting Application and IIS didn't help

Comment: No need to start Azure Server. you need to restart application pool and sql services

Comment: can you please explain to me how can I restart SQL services which are on AZure SQL Server ?

Comment: closing connections is not the answer in Azure, you need to have a retry policy. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5783119/1033684